Nullity of a self-dual connection
I consider Yang-Mills theory in the critical dimension $4$ on a $SU(2)$-bundle with positive Chern-Class. It is well known that self-dual connections ($*F=F$) are minimizers of the Yang-Mills functional $\int_M \vert F\vert^2 \, dv$. It is also well known that the functional is invariant under the action of conformal diffeomorphisms on connections.
My question is: is the nullity(i.e. the kernel of the second variation) exactly given by those conformal transformations? In particular, on $S^4$ does the nullity of an instanton has exactly the dimension of the Möbius group?
